# Can I use a tuple to index into a multidimensional array in Nim?

Tags: arrays, tuples, nim-lang

Say I have a 2d array:

```
var a = [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

And a tuple:

```
type
  Point: tuple[x, y: int]

let p: Point = (1,1)
```

I can index into `a` via `a[p.x][p.y]`, but is there a shorter way?

For example in Python's numpy I could do `a[p]` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. But as usual, you can add functions that you consider useful, even if the language doesn't support them natively:

```
proc `[]`[N, T](xs: openarray[array[N, T]], p: (int, int)): T = xs[p[0]][p[1]]
proc `[]`[T](xs: openarray[seq[T]], p: (int, int)): T = xs[p[0]][p[1]]

type Point = tuple[x, y: int]
let p: Point = (1,1)

var a = [[1,2],[3,4]]
var b = @[@[1,2],@[3,4]]

echo a[p]
echo b[p]
```